# Is there a way to draw lines on a seekbar in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, media, seekbar

I have a seekbar (progress bar - horizontal) that is used for media playback. Currently, there is a thumb that people can drag back and forth to change the position of the media being played.

What I am trying to achieve is this: a user can click a button while the media is playing, and then a line marking that position on the seekbar appears.

I've been looking for like a day and a half now and can't really find anything. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: One approach, not very convenient but working, is to subclass `SeekBar` and override `onDraw(Canvas)`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That is kind of the approach I was thinking about, but I'm not really sure how to go about implementing it. I was thinking I could draw the line in onDraw() and then anytime the button is pressed, I call that method?

Comment: Well, that's why it's less than convenient :) `onDraw()` is a callback that only Android calls when it knows it must refresh the content of the view. So each time you change it (add another line etc.), you must manually call `view.invalidate()` and then Android will redraw it. You must also store all the state (line positions) inside the view so you can redraw whenever asked to.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Okay I think that is starting to make sense. Correct me if I have this wrong: to forcefully call onDraw, I have to call view.invalidate. The 'view' would be a reference to the seekbar? And could I just store the positions in an array, and whenever a new line is requested, I just add that position to the array? Then in onDraw() I use the array to actually draw the lines?

Comment: Yes, in your `SeekBar` subclass you'll have this array. You should also add a method to your subclass: `addMark`. That method then calls `invalidate()` on itself, so it's not the concern of the user of the class.